# Funny IP address. Please help

Tags: ip, ip-address

So I have a computer on my network that will not connect to the internet. It says it's connecting on IP address 169.254.114.198 which is an unassigned address. None of my other computers are having problems and they are all on my network. What is going on?

Answer (score 16):

Your machine is unable to obtain an IP address via DHCP.  If you are using a DHCP server on your network you should make sure it has available addresses to distribute.  If so, troubleshoot the physical connection between your PC and DHCP server.

Comment: This is your answer.  Every time I have seen this it has been some sort of hardware issue.  Bad cable, bad port, bad card.

Comment: Nunya is right, if the thing is even plugged in.

Comment: If it is not plugged in then the link would not be there and it would not even assign any IP

Comment: Proy, that's an auto-assigned IP address. The kind you get if you're not plugged in.

Comment: @John/Nunya - Proy is correct.  You're auto-assigned address of 169. won't occur unless you actually have a cable plugged in.  The NIC won't assign itself that address unless it's receiving a signal from another source.

Comment: @John - Let me clarify my statement above that you are of course also correct in the fact that the 169. is auto-assigned (you said that not Proy)

Answer (score 5):

That IP address is known as an APIPA which stands for Automatic Private IP Addressing

Read here for more information: http://www.petri.co.il/whats_apipa.htm